# How to configure netMessagingBinding in BizTalk Server 2010

Tags: wcf, azure, biztalk

I have windows Azure SDK 1.6, BizTalk Server 2010 and Windows EAI SDK April 2012 CTP installed.

While creating a receive location with WCF-Custom adapter I have to use netMessagingBinding, which dont appear in the binding type list of `WCF-Custom` Transport properties.

I have added following sections in machine.config file under Microsoft.Net Framework 4.0.30319

Under bindingExtensions

```
<add name="netMessagingBinding" 
     type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingBindingCollectionElement, 
    Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

Under bindingElementsExtension

```
<add name="netMessagingTransport" 
    type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingTransportExtensionElement, 
    Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

What else am I missing that binding type is still not appearing?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://tycholien.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/bindings-for-biztalk-2010-and-azure-service-bus/) worked for me:

1. Install Windows Azure Libraries for .NET (Azure Appfabric SDK). Note that Azure Appfabric [SDK 1.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=29988) is now out.
2. Either run [RelayConfigurationInstaller.exe](http://blog.wadewegner.com/2010/05/net-framework-4-0-and-the-azure-appfabric-sdk/) with a file setting the requiredRuntime for .NET 4, or do this by [manually adding](http://tycholien.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/bindings-for-biztalk-2010-and-azure-service-bus/) the binding element extensions and binding extensions to **BOTH** 32 bit and 64 bit machine configs as you've done above.
3. Restart BTS Admin Console

*Edit by Anon User:*

- 32 bit config is in here : %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
- 64 bit config is in here : %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config