# Where is the RelayConfigurationInstaller.exe tool in Azure SDK 1.7?

Tags: azure, machine.config, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

I can't seem to find the **Azure Service Bus Relay configuration tool** - `RelayConfigurationInstaller.exe` in the [June 2012 SDK release](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29988). It used to be trivial to [fix the relay configuration errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12314895/175679) when the WCF extensions were not properly installed in the `machine.config`.

Here is the error message:

> *An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/bindings: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.*

I'm trying to upgrade from **Azure SDK 1.6** (*Nov. 2011*) to **Azure SDK 1.7** (*June 2012*) and receiving this message. It seems the installer didn't automatically upgrade my `machine.config` settings from 1.6 to 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN Release Notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh667331.aspx), the tool `RelayConfigurationInstaller.exe` has been deprecated in Azure SDK 1.7:

#### From MSDN:

> *The **RelayConfigurationInstaller.exe tool is no longer shipped with the SDK**. This tool enabled you to add the Machine.config settings necessary for Service Bus bindings to be supported in the configuration file. The recommended way to add these bindings now is to add a reference to the Service Bus by installing the NuGet package. NuGet adds the correct entries to the configuration file. For more information, see the NuGet gallery.*

I guess you are left to **manually update** your `machine.config` to change all references to `Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0` to `Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.7.0.0`.

Alternately - you can remove the extensions entirely from your `machine.config`, but you would have to add them to the existing applications using the service bus extensions.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the release notes, a key recommendation is to use `app.config` for these entries and not `machine.config`. Starting SDK1.6, all subsequent Azure SDKs are SideBySide installable. So you can keep SDK 1.6 installed and then add SDK 1.7. Entries in `machine.config` do no support this so all your applications on that box will either use 1.6 or be auto upgraded to 1.7 if we continued with that approach. Thus the change in recommendation to start using `app.config` files for these entries, letting you decide on a per project basis to move between SDK versions.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I suppose hindsight is 20/20, it would have been great if they never added them to the `machine.config` to begin with. ;-)